# Do you know of any web-based university course that is entirely Mathematica based?

Tags: reference-request, education

Does anybody known of a web-based university course entirely built with *Mathematica*? I mean one where the whole course (lectures/labs/exams) is presented in *Mathematica* FrontEnd form.

My point is that *Mathematica* is very user-friendly, supporting the principle "if you can visualize this data/process, you must do it". I suppose this feature makes *Mathematica* very attractive for wide use in university courses, if not now then in the near future. So I am looking for exising examples. Any links?

Comment: Such courses may exist here and there, but mostly created by professors who are at the same time expert Mathematica users / programmers. I know of only one reference of the kind you look for: [Math Desktop](http://www.deltasoft.at/) software (and it is not web-shared). I am sure others will add more links. But my point is, I am not aware of any general framework for this, and creating a complete such  solution in Mathematica requires a very significant programming effort. But I agree that M still is an ideal patform for such things.

Comment: The state of Victoria (Australia) will be heading down this path soon for high school math courses but your question is for university courses. I think they have or are about to trial implementing their exams in Mathematica with a sub-group of schools.

Comment: I gave a course on [Mathematica as a tool for astronomy and physics](http://www.astro.uni-koeln.de/staff/roellig/de/node/3) completely done in form of  Mathematica notebooks.

Comment: @Mike It's amazing how almost no-one in the education system in Victoria knows about [the Mathematica trial](http://www.vcaa.vic.edu.au/Pages/vce/studies/mathematics/cas/castrial.aspx). Also, you can (try to) get approval to use almost any CAS software, see [Approved Calculators](http://www.vcaa.vic.edu.au/Pages/vce/studies/mathematics/approvedcalculators.aspx).

Comment: @Simon there are probably some good reasons for that which I would share in private. BTW are you in (still) Melbourne?

Comment: @Mike: Yep, still in Mlbn. I sent you an email.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

University of Southern Maine has some Mathematica based courses:

1. [Engineering Tools: Mathematica](http://usm.maine.edu/engineering/egn-181) ([notebooks](http://eelinux.ee.usm.maine.edu/courses/egn181/))
2. [Circuits I: Steady-State Analysis](http://usm.maine.edu/engineering/ele-216) ([notebooks](http://eelinux.ee.usm.maine.edu/courses/ele216/lectures/))
3. [Digital Signal Processing](http://usm.maine.edu/engineering/ele-486) ([notebooks](http://eelinux.ee.usm.maine.edu/courses/ele486/lectures/))
4. [Digital Image Processing](http://usm.maine.edu/engineering/ele-489) ([notebooks](http://eelinux.ee.usm.maine.edu/courses/ele489/lectures/))

Answer (score 9):

A pioneering web site in this respect is the one by [James Kelly](http://www.physics.umd.edu/enp/jjkelly/), who unfortunately passed away in 2007 as the linked web page states. His lecture notes are very high quality and all written as notebooks.

Answer (score 6):

There's a [second year mathematics](http://ftp.physics.uwa.edu.au/pub/MATH2200/) and a [computation physics](http://ftp.physics.uwa.edu.au/pub/Computational/) course taught by [Paul Abbott](http://internal.physics.uwa.edu.au/~paul/) at the University of Western Australia that uses *Mathematica* for all of the lectures, workshops and assessments.

The maths course uses a customised stylesheet and the assessment notebooks have automated FTP uploading to the assignment dropbox. However, [most](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rest.html) of the assessment notebooks are normally only available during the times that the course is being taught.