# Mathematica Courses or Bootcamps?

Tags: reference-request, education

Related questions and link:

[Do you know of any web-based university course that is entirely Mathematica based?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16635/do-you-know-of-any-web-based-university-course-that-is-entirely-mathematica-base)

[What is the best Mathematica tutorial for young people?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/733/what-is-the-best-mathematica-tutorial-for-young-people)

http://www.wolfram.com/training/courses/

I want to introduce my 24 year old step-son to Mathematica.  I have an agenda in this.  I'd like to lure him into the "family" business and view Mathematica skills and the kind of thinking and problem solving that they foster as essential.

Tutoring or instructing him myself just brings far too many family dynamics into play.

So, does anyone know of any Mathematica "bootcamps", like the intensive bootcamps for Python or Web development?  I'd welcome either courses locally in the NYC area, residential courses in other parts of the U.S., or even a comprehensive on-line course.

He'll learn best with some structure and human interaction (even if on-line), so just handing him Leonid's book won't solve the problem.

Comment: This is an interesting question.  MOOC's are offered which highlight and rely on MatLab as well as other Math/Programming implementations.  A MOOC that relies on and highlights Mathematica would be a good thing!

Comment: So you're basically doing `Manipulate[son]`. Nice :) Hope it will work!

Comment: @belisariusisforth -- I think of it as a custom function: `Nudge[son]` ;-)

Comment: @Jagra nice idea - keep on polluting the global namespace rather than putting it in a package :-)

Comment: I found this a while ago: [Sabio Academy](http://sabioacademy.com/). I am not sure about their online course offerings but maybe it is a start? Personally I am appalled when MOOCs like Coursera force me to use (and therefore learn) tools like MatLab or Octave or R or what have you in order to enroll in their course. To me learning a similar (and maybe even inferior?) tool is a clear no-go right there, as that to me seems a clear waste of time and effort (I am a practioner, not a programmer). Why not at least allow the tool somebody is most comfortable with?

Comment: ... as an aside I quite liked the Academy's reasoning for using Mathematica in their teaching: [Why Mathematica](http://en.sabioacademy.com/research/courses/why-mathematica/). I refer to it as "A Mathematica User's Apology" and use it myself to `Nudge @@@ {Offspring1, Offspring2, ...}`.

Comment: I discovered [Wolfram Education Portal](http://education.wolfram.com/index.html) and [Algebra Topics](http://education.wolfram.com/algebra/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the schedule at Wolfram U, there is always a lineup of events there, many are free:

https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/calendar

for instance Daily Study Groups are new and popular:

https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/special-event/study-groups

For a program with full immersion I really recommend Wolfram Summer School:

- https://education.wolfram.com/summer/school
- https://blog.wolfram.com/2020/07/30/pandemic-inspired-innovations-make-for-the-best-wolfram-summer-school-yet

Also the Wolfram Technology Conference is around the corner. This year it will be virtual. Lot's of fun there:

https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2020